# Nuxt3: how two chain two fetches?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I am trying to chain two `fetch` in Nuxt3, with the second one calling an URL based on the result of the first one and the resulting "variable" to be used in the Vue component.

I'm trying with

```html
<script setup>
const url = "myurl";
const { data } = await useFetch(url);

watch(data, async () => {
  // do something with the result
  url2 = data.value.result
  const variable = await useFetch(url2);
});
</script>
```

but it looks like the block inside the watch is not able to modify the values of the variables at all (e.g. if I define it outside and try to update it inside, even with hard coded values)

Am I missing something very obvious here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this works perfectly fine, since all the fetching will be awaited

```html
<script setup>
const { data } = await useFetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
console.log('data', data.value.userId)
const { data: photos } = await useFetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/${data.value.userId}`)
console.log('data2', photos.value)
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    first data: {{ data }}
  </div>
  <hr />
  <div>
    photos: {{ photos }}
  </div>
</template>
```

[image]